# Freezing Python 3.6

Tags: pyinstaller, cx-freeze, python-3.6

To utilize the inherent UTF-8 support for windows console, I wanted to freeze my script in python 3.6, but I'm unable to find any. Am I missing something, or none of the freezing modules updated for 3.6 yet?

Otherwise I'll just keep a 3.5.2 frozen version and a 3.6 script version for computers with English consoles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bytecode format changed for Python 3.6 but I just pushed a change to cx_Freeze that adds support for it. You can compile it yourself or wait for the next release -- which should be sometime this week.